# Getting the URL without using request object

Tags: node.js, express

In Node (Express) is there anyway to get the url without using request object?
Or is there any module on NPM I can use for this purpose? The reason being I want to get it in a module where I dont have access to the request object!

Thanks :-)

Comment: Why not pass the url to the module? There is no way to do what you're asking. The request object contains all of the request-related information.

Comment: Or pass the request?

Comment: Yes passing req.url is doable, just wondering if there is any better/cleaner way instead of passing this req.url/req/... in a chain... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Getting the requested URL without a request object is not possible, unless your URL is sent using Ajax maybe?

There is a module that simplifies the request and response objects called [easyreq](https://www.npmjs.org/package/easyreq)